# Associar variável final a outra referência em expressão lambda

Tags: java, expressões-lambda, programação-funcional

Eu estava desenvolvendo um código que utiliza expressões lambda, onde as variáveis fora do escopo da expressão devem ser declaradas como `final`. Então surgiu a dúvida: eu posso associar a variável declarada como final a uma outra referência declarada dentro do escopo da expressão lambda?

Suponhamos que eu tenha o código abaixo que não compila:

```java
public void testLambda() {
  ExecutorService executorService = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();
  String nonFinalString = "random";
  // ... outras operacoes aleatorias
  executorService.execute(() -> {
    // erro de compilacao: variavel deve ser final ou "effective final"
    System.out.println(nonFinalString)
  })
}
```

Eu poderia fazer o seguinte workaround:

```
public void testLambda() {
  ExecutorService executorService = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();
  String nonFinalString = "random";
  // ... outras operacoes aleatorias
  executorService.execute(() -> {
    // declarar uma nova variavel e associar com a variavel que desejo
    String inScopeString = nonFinalString; 
    System.out.println(nonFinalString)
  })
}
```

Minha dúvida é se a variável declarada dentro do escopo `inScopeVariable` é uma variável `final` ou não. A solução proposta acima seria considerada uma prática ruim?